# How to make this section responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

[image: Image Section]

Hey everyone,
How do I make this section responsive at 768px

```css
.AppleContent {
    background-color: #9ACD32;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 200px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-1">
        <div class="AppleContent">
            <i class="fas fa-apple-alt fa-3x"></i>
            <h3 class="font-weight">Completely synergize resource taxing relationships</h3>
            <p id="secondparagraph">Professionally cultivate one-to-one customer service with robust ideas. Dynamically innovate resource-leveling customer service for state of the art customer service.</p>
        </div>
</section>
```

Comment: for responsive you need to add meta tag of viewport

Comment: Responsive in what way? How should the layout change on 768px?

Comment: Yes, the layout and the font should change on 768 to look better not as it looks now

Comment: use media query

Answer (score 0):

You have given absolute values for padding `padding: 50px 200px;`... which is why when you go to smaller sizes, the content looks off;

To get the exact look that you're looking for, Try giving it relative values (instead of absolute values). A percentage like `padding: 5% 10%;` or like l have done below (relative to view height and view width)...

Below is the code sample

```css
.AppleContent {
  background-color: #9ACD32;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10vh 20vw;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-1">
  <div class="AppleContent">
    <i class="fas fa-apple-alt fa-3x"></i>
    <h3 class="font-weight">Completely synergize resource taxing relationships</h3>
    <p id="secondparagraph">Professionally cultivate one-to-one customer service with robust ideas. Dynamically innovate resource-leveling customer service for state of the art customer service.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```